# 'never' properties cannot be set inside the counstructor

Tags: properties, haxe

So, the question is in the title. I declared some properties in my classes using 'never' keyword so I may set the values of these properties only once, in the constructor. However, I get the following error:

Cannot access field or identifier %name% for writing

Example of the problematic code:

```
class TreeAbility
{

        public var id(default, never):String;
        public var maxLvl(default, never):Int;

        public function new(id:String, maxLvl:Int) 
        {
            Assert.assert(maxLvl > 0);

            this.id = id; (*)
            this.maxLvl = maxLvl; (*)
            this.currentLvl = 0;
        }

}
```

The lines marked with (*) throw the access error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the *never* write property means that writing/setting the variable is never allowed, not even within the constructor. See: https://haxe.org/manual/class-field-property.html

Perhaps you are looking for the *final* keyword, which is coming in Haxe 4. For instance fields, it allows assignment to the variable only from the class constructor. Confirmed here: https://haxe.org/download/version/4.0.0-preview.2/ and https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/6584

Comment: _never_ described in details on the old version of the site. It also contains the examples of assigning a value to a never-write property inside the constructor.
But OK, maybe _never_ worked that way sometime in the past
http://old.haxe.org/ref/properties

Comment: Just read the 4.0.0 changelog. Now I have a assumption that only static never-write properties can be set in the constructor

Comment: On the old website, the example I see using the "never" property isn't writing to "numItems". "container.numItems" would call "get_numItems()" behind the scenes, but no variable called "numItems" would exist on the instance in the final code.